# Domain redirection to the same page and Google

Tags: http, redirect, seo

We developed a website for a client and he has purchased the .com, .net, .info versions of the domain.

Is there any way to redirect all to the same page without being considered by Google as duplicated content and therefore penalized in the ranking position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [permanent redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

Comment: As far as I know, the duplicate content penalty is a myth. If you have the same site on 3 different domains, the sum of its value to users is the same as if the site was on only one domain. You are not penalised. Also, you do not get 3 times the value.